# groovy - why is the connection getting closed using this code block

Tags: oracle, groovy

```
    DbService dbService = new DbService(DB_NAME);
    GroovyRowResult row = null;
    try {
        MyClass myObj  = new MyClass(dbService.singleRow(query));
        return myObj;
    } finally {
        dbService.cleanup();
    }
```

---

```
import groovy.sql.Sql;
public class DbService {
private Sql sql;
public void cleanup() {
    if (null != sql) {
        sql.close();
    }
}
```

---

> Sep 28, 2015 9:19:15 PM groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand execute
>   WARNING: Failed to execute: select * from mytable where id=9 and
>   rownum <=1 because: Closed Connection
>   java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3908)
>     at groovy.sql.Sql.createStatement(Sql.java:4288)    at
>   groovy.sql.Sql.access$800(Sql.java:228)   at
>   groovy.sql.Sql$CreateStatementCommand.execute(Sql.java:4525)  at
>   groovy.sql.Sql.getAbstractStatement(Sql.java:4342)    at
>   groovy.sql.Sql.getStatement(Sql.java:4349)    at
>   groovy.sql.Sql.access$1000(Sql.java:228)  at
>   groovy.sql.Sql$QueryCommand.runQuery(Sql.java:4637)   at
>   groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand.execute(Sql.java:4553)    at
>   groovy.sql.Sql.rows(Sql.java:1699)    at
>   groovy.sql.Sql.rows(Sql.java:1617)    at
>   com.mycompany.qa.database.DbService.singleRow(DbService.java:146)

---

Comment: Difficult to say as well as difficult to reproduce. Any further details?

Comment: Assuming `dbService.singleRow` calls `firstRow`.  This closes the connection. It's in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. The documentation is correct. This has more to do with the additional code that I have not posted that is causing it.